# How to convert this Xpath to CSS Selector?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

How to convert the below Xpath to CSS? Please help

```
//input[@title='11']//ancestor::div[@class='item-row centerVertical']//child::bs-check-box-combo-box//child::div//child::ul[@class='dropdown-menu dropdown-list dropdown-menu-right show']//child::li//child::a//child::span[@class='useEllipses']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not convert that into `css selector.`

Because you are using `ancestor` which means to traverse DOM in upward direction.

CSS Selector does not have support to `traverse upwards`, they can traverse only downwards.

This is limitation of CSS, and in these type of scenarios XPATH should be preferred.

Comment: Agree with you! I would only edit your answer saying `This is one of limitations of CSS`

Comment: @Prophet : yes that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You would just move the ancestor part to the left:

```
div.item-row.centerVertical input[title="11"]
```

There's no reason to go up and down the dom like that with your selectors. It's very inefficient